# How to parse an string of words containing quotation marks

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing, split

I have a string like this, as you can see it consists of property/value pairs separated by space. For example: `GRID "GLOBAL"` or `COORD 0`

```
  GRID "GLOBAL"  LABEL "A"  DIR "X"  COORD 0  GRIDTYPE  " "
```

The TEXT values are inside quotation marks but the NUMERICAL ones are not.

**What is the best and fastest method to split it into an array of strings like this:**

```
  [GRID ,"GLOBAL", LABEL, "A", DIR, "X", COORD, 0, GRIDTYPE, " "]
```

The below solution does not work, because there is also space between " " in the value after `GRIDTYPE`.

```
var tokens = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good place for Regex:

```
string[] split = Regex.Matches(inputString, "(\\w+|\".*?\")")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value)
                      .ToArray();
```

[See it on Regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/LMbfYX/1)